# How to move /var to another existing partition?

Tags: debian, partition

I have a / partition which contains /var and is too small.
I have another existing partition with enough space.

Here is my df:

```
File system          Size. Occ. Avai. %Ful. Monté sur
/dev/sda1             5,0G  4,5G  289M  95% /
tmpfs                 242M     0  242M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                   10M  2,7M  7,4M  27% /dev
tmpfs                 242M     0  242M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda2              15G  406M   14G   3% /home
```

How can I move the /var folder from sda1 to sda2 ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Go into single user mode, and make sure any process writing to `/var` is stopped. (Check with `lsof -n | grep /var`)

- `mkdir -p /home/var`
- `rsync -va /var/. /home/var/.`
- `mv /var /var.old` # you can remove `/var.old` when you are done to reclaim the space
- `mkdir -p /var`
- `mount -o bind /home/var /var`
- update your `/etc/fstab` to make the bind-mount permanent.

`/etc/fstab`

```
 /home/var /var        none    bind
```

Comment: Thks! How can I enter into single user mode? Will 'var' folder stay in the /home?

Comment: Yes there would always be a `/home/var` directory if you solve the problem this way.  One way you can get into single user mode by rebooting, and choosing single user mode from the Boot menu.

Comment: I am not really sure if this will work fine all the time. If you are using a more recent version (wheezy) you may be OK as it has a /run filesystem. OTOH: early in the boot process files can get opened in /var before it is bind mounted.

Comment: @cstamas, Having /var on a separate filesystem **is supported**, and always has been.  Having /var on a separate is even suggested as being a good thing in FHS, and the official Debian docs.

Comment: Ok, I think you are right. It was just strange to me to do this with bind mounts.

Comment: I'm on Debian, Linux version 2.6.32. I have no access to a boot menu as this is a hosted server...

Comment: My home is a software raid `md` device. How can I make sure that `md0` comes up before binding occurs?

Comment: @Jérémie From the command line you can  go to single-user mode so that there isn't rw activity on the directory during the process  by typing *init 1*

Comment: I can't rename `/var`  because the "resource is busy" :/ There is no output with `lsof | grep var` nor with `ps aux | grep var`

Comment: @aliopi - you'll need sudo in front of it as some of the processes with open file handles to /var will run under root

Comment: I'm on Debian 12 and this caused errors when loading several drivers, such as iwlwifi. I dodged the problem by using the above solution on very specific directories, like `/var/lib/postgresql` (which takes around 60% of the space used by /var in my config)

Comment: Hi @Zoredache, are you sure that `rsync -va /var /home/var` is correct ? I think this should be `rsync -va /var /home`

Comment: @mbh86 `/home/var` is correct. Most people already had other files and directories under `/home`. If you use the command you suggest you would destroy any existing files under `/home` and replace it with **only** the contents of `/var`. This is why I sync into a sub-directory. There is almost certainly better (more complicated) options I could have suggested that would have relocated both `/home` and `/var` into a new location, but I was trying to give a minimal answer that the poster and other people could adapt to their needs if they understood the basics.

Comment: I see you edited @Zoredache, thank you. The initial command was creating `/home/var/var`. And yes your point is relevant, my suggestion was not safe enough. I think the cleaner way would then be `rsync -va /var/ /home/var` with the trailing slash `/` after the source. Thank you for replying quickly :)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use:

```
 mkdir /home/var
 <move contents of /var to /home/var -- however you want; EX: mv /var/* /home/var>
 mv /var /var.old
 ln -s /home/var /var
```

This seems a lot easier than messing around with the fstab and mount stuff.

Comment: Not sure why anyone would have down-vote this.  This would work perfectly fine.  A sym-link should work fine.  I just use bind mounts for other things, so I tend to think of those first.

Comment: To add to this, it may not be as safe, but it does in fact work.  I've recently done this on a machine prior to placing it in production.  Iw ould use caution if it's a machine that's been in use or has a lot of processes running.  In my case, it was a fresh server meant to run only tomcat.

Comment: Symlinking /var works, but instead of doing so I prefer to put an entry in /etc/fstab, to remember myself on which partition/volume I put what, and why (you can add comments). This way is also more understandable to me what I have to change in configuration if I need to change something in my hardware.

Comment: I can't see how this would work. I want it to work, but basic things like init use /var, don't they?

Comment: I just tried this here on my arch linux, since this was also my typical approach. But it fails. The system does not boot when your var is a symlink to a mount defined in fstab (like /home here). Var has to be bind-mounted, see accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

## Move `/var` without changing into single-user mode

When I took over a new virtual server that had been provisioned for me by my employer’s hosting company, I created extra logical volumes for `var` and `home` which had been regular directories in the root partition. Since the virtual server provider didn’t provide a KVM-like interface by which I could access the server in single-user mode, the above answers were not applicable to my setup. I hope this answer is useful for others in a similar situation (I've kept the LVM details but these can be skipped as it’s not particularly relevant whether the new filesystem is created on a logical volume or a disk partition).

#### Create and use a new `/var` filesystem with LVM

Create the filesystem for the new `var` volume, mount it (using a temporary directory) and copy files from the current `/var` to the new filesystem.  When copying files with `rsync`, use its `-a, --archive` option to preserve time-stamps, ownership, modes, etc. and its `-X, --xattrs` option to preserve the extended attributes such as the security labels used by AppArmor and SELinux.

```
sudo lvcreate -L 60GB -n var VolGroup00
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/VolGroup00/var
sudo mkdir /var.new
sudo mount /dev/VolGroup00/var /var.new
sudo rsync -raX /var/ /var.new/
```

#### Update the filesystem table

Configure the new filesystem to be used as a new mount-point for `/var` by adding the following line to `/etc/fstab`.  Note that `0` is used as the pass number (last field) so that the filesystem won’t be automatically checked (`fsck`) after a certain number of reboots (I’ve no access to log in to the server in single-user mode).

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-var    /var    ext4  defaults  0 0
```

Since I can’t change into single-user mode, reboot the computer to use this new volume as `/var`.

#### Recover disk space from the root filesystem

After the machine has restarted, carry out the following steps to clean up the temporary directory and remove the old `/var` files from the root filesystem:

1. Remove the temporary mount point:

   ```
   sudo rmdir /var.new
   ```
2. Create a new mount point to create an alternative path to the files on the old `/var` directory on the root filesystem (it’s currently “masked” by the new `/var` filesystem mounted on the directory):

   ```
   sudo mkdir /old-root
   sudo mount /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-root /old-root/
   sudo rm -rf /old-root/var/*
   sudo umount /old-root/
   sudo rmdir /old-root/
   ```

Comment: Do you think it's safe to have `VolGroup00-root` mounted twice as Read-Write ? IMO it would corrupt most of commodity FSes.